# Problema consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema con una consulta, en realidad nunca he realizado este tipo de consulta, lo he intentado pero aun no logro lo que quiero, asi que explico lo que quiero hacer con la siguiente tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta tabla, como pueden ver en usuario_ad los usuarios se repiten, ya que son usuarios padres que agregan usuarios hijos, por ejemplo, danielad agrego a pepe, yhonier, lucho, etc... lo que quiero hacer es que con base al usuario_ad me muestre el numero de usuarios que esta a cargo de cada usuario padre, osea algo como danielad 4, andresad 2, angiead 3, paolaad 3, en mi caso se podra hacer un count asi?

Comment: ¿De donde obtienes 'danielad', 'andresad', 'angiead', 'paolaad'?

Comment: de otra tabla que maneja los usuarios de sesion, esta relacionada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es para contar a los usuarios padre sería así:

```
SELECT COUNT(nombre) FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_ad = 'danielad';  
SELECT COUNT(nombre) FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_ad = 'andresad';  
SELECT COUNT(nombre) FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_ad = 'angiead';  
SELECT COUNT(nombre) FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_ad = 'paolaad';
```

En una sola línea:

```
SELECT COUNT(nombre), usuario_ad FROM usuarios GROUP BY usuario_ad;
```

Comment: excelente, no existe forma de hacer esto en una sola consulta?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(nombre), usuario_ad FROM usuarios GROUP BY usuario_ad;